# Quiero concatenar dos variables en sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
 create proceduro SP_concatena

    DECLARE @GLOBAL_TOTP AS CHAR(100)   
    DECLARE @PLACA AS CHAR(7)
    set @GLOBAL_TOTP='hol'
    set @PLACA='as'
    set @GLOBAL_TOTP=@GLOBAL_TOTP+ @PLACA
    print @GLOBAL_TOTP
```

quiero q esa dos variables de concatenen
solo sale:
hol

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es simplemente concatenar los valores de las variables puedes hacer algo como esto

```sql
DECLARE @GLOBAL_TOTP AS VARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @PLACA VARCHAR(6)
SET @GLOBAL_TOTP='hol'
SET @PLACA='as'

SET @GLOBAL_TOTP = @GLOBAL_TOTP + @PLACA
select @GLOBAL_TOTP
```

Sin embargo si deseas, crear o ejecutar una sentencia preparada te recomiendo este enfoque:

```sql
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnList varchar(75)
DECLARE @city varchar(75)

SET @columnList = 'AddressID, AddressLine1, City'
SET @city = '''London'''
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM Person.Address WHERE City = ' + @city

EXEC (@sqlCommand
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el timepo, resulto

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas tratando de concatenar CHAR y este provoca esos espacios que vez en vez de eso trata con datos de tipo VARCHAR como te muestro aqui.

```
DECLARE @GLOBAL_TOTP AS VARCHAR(100)   
    DECLARE @PLACA AS VARCHAR(7)
    set @GLOBAL_TOTP='hol'
    set @PLACA='as'
    set @GLOBAL_TOTP=@GLOBAL_TOTP+ @PLACA
    print @GLOBAL_TOTP
```

Saludos.

Un ejemplo.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1282477822fd218dbf84df50ff7a803d

Comment: genial, muchas gracias

Comment: Si esta respuesta fue la correcta no olvides marcarla como correcta saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Hola una mejor opción es usar la funcion **CONCAT**. de esta manera.

```
set @GLOBAL_TOTP=CONCAT(@GLOBAL_TOTP,@PLACA)
```